# Anonymous function warning

Tags: javascript

I have a problem on my code and I don't know how to fix it.
Where I write "IMPORTANT HERE" the console tell me the function(e) is anonymous. How can I resolve my problem?

```
(function() {

    var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm'),
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'),
    inputsLength = inputs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputsLength; i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            check[e.target.id](e.target.id); 
        });
    }

    theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {   //IMPORTANT HERE

        var result = true;
        for (var i in check) {
            result = check[i](i) && result;
        }
        if (result) {
            alert('Le formulaire est bien rempli.');
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });

    theForm.addEventListener('reset', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputsLength; i++) {
            inputs[i].className = '';
        }
        deactivateTooltips();
    });
})();
```

Comment: Turn off JS warnings (this is not an error) in the console, or give a name to that anonymous function.

Comment: how can i give her a name?

Comment: ??? Like to any function: `.addEventListener('submit', function NAME (e) {...`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)